# Add the positive multiples of 2 that are less than or equal to 300.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

When I did this problem, I got $$\sum_{n=1}^{150}2n=22650$$
However, the correct answer that the professor stated was 45300 which is $$45300=22650\cdot2$$

Comment: There are $150$ numbers in the list, and the average of them is $151$. So the sum is $150\times151$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can be a good sanity check for these things. It's [surprisingly good](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+%2B+4+%2B+6+%2B+...+%2B+300) at interpreting less than rigorous inputs too.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Isn't that still 22650?

Comment: @Mutternibic Yes, the sum of the numbers in the set $\{2,4,6,\ldots,300\}$ is $150\times151=22650$.

Answer (score 1):

The professors answer was incorrect, and it seems like the the correct answer is:$\sum_{n=1}^{150}2n=22650$